# R: Aggregating a list of column names mapped to row numbers based off of a condition in a data frame

Tags: r

Scaled down my dataframe looks like this:

```
+---+------------+-------------+
|   |   Label1   |   Label2    |
+---+------------+-------------+
| 1 |      T     |     F       |
| 2 |      F     |     F       |
| 3 |      T     |     T       |
+---+------------+-------------+
```

I need to create a list of lists that map the column names to all the row numbers that have a false boolean as their value. For the above example it would look something like this:

{"Label1" : (2), "Label2" : (1,2)}

I am currently doing it as so:

```
myList = with(data.frame(which(!myDataFrame, arr.ind = TRUE)), list("colNames" = names(myDataFrame)[col], "rows" = row))

l = list()
count = 1;
for (i in myList[["colNames"]]) {
  tmpRowNum = myList[["rows"]][[count]];
  tmpList = l[[i]];
  if (is.null(tmpList)) {
    tmpList = list();
  }
  l[[i]] = c(tmpList, list(tmpRowNum))
  count = count + 1;
}
```

This does work, but as I am new to R I can only assume there is a more efficient method of doing this. The with function creates two separate lists that I essentially have to combine to get the result that I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
df <- data.frame(Label1=c("T","F","T"),Label2=c("F","F","T"))

lapply(df,function(x) which(x=="F"))

$Label1
[1] 2

$Label2
[1] 1 2
```

**EDIT** To get the same by row, use `apply` with margin=1:

```
apply(df,1,function(x) which(x=="F"))
```

To get a vector of the "F"s in row 2:

```
res <- apply(df,1,function(x) which(x=="F"))
res[[2]]
 1      2
```

Comment: Is there any possibility that it could be done in the opposite direction? Mapping the rownumber to the list of column names that it has a false value for?

Answer (score 0):

One useful way to get the row/column index is with `which` and `arr.ind`

```
i1 <- which(df=="F", arr.ind=TRUE)
```